# Units don't move until end of turn

Tags: civilization-5

This has been really frustrating for me: My units don't actually move when I release the right mouse button, but when I end the turn. (If I tell a unit to automate its movement, it moves *during* my turn.) How do I get them to actually move when I tell them to?

This makes attacking enemy units incredibly difficult because my units just move onto the tiles as they move away!

Comment: This sounds precisely the opposite of how it behaves for me - the only actions performed at the turn's end are queued movement actions from previous turns and automatic actions. Are you positive you've made no modification to the game files and are using no special mods?

Comment: It sounds like you are giving units long distance orders -- orders that are outside the range of their current movement abilities for that turn. Are you experiencing this even when moving units a single tile?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue on my MacBook by restarting the game.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too as it is different behavior than Civ 3, but I believe if you have queued movements, it will perform the queued movement right after you hit Next Turn, but they will still count towards the current turns moves.  It is to give you a chance to change up a unit's orders before ending the turn.

If you make a command to move during a turn, however, it is executed immediately.